How to show all dates of the year weekly
I want to show all date of year grouped weekly and show every weekday in one row of table.
code in below was shows all date of year: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4044939)
$now = mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2024);
$aYearLater = $now + 31536000;
$allDates = Array();

$friday = strtotime('Next Friday', strtotime('-1 Day', $now));
$saturday = strtotime('Next Saturday', strtotime('-1 Day', $now));
$sunday = strtotime('Next Sunday', strtotime('-1 Day', $now));
$monday = strtotime('Next Monday', strtotime('-1 Day', $now));
$tuesday = strtotime('Next Tuesday', strtotime('-1 Day', $now));
$wednesday = strtotime('Next Wednesday', strtotime('-1 Day', $now));
$thursday = strtotime('Next Thursday', strtotime('-1 Day', $now));

while(1){
    if($saturday > $aYearLater)
        break 1;
    $a = array('date'=>date('Y-m-d l', $saturday));
    $b = array('daynum'=>date('w', $saturday,'','','en'));
    $allDates[] = array_merge($a,$b); 
    if($sunday > $aYearLater)
        break 1;
    $a = array('date'=>date('Y-m-d l', $sunday));
    $b = array('daynum'=>date('w', $sunday,'','','en'));
    $allDates[] = array_merge($a,$b); 
    if($monday > $aYearLater)
        break 1;
    $a = array('date'=>date('Y-m-d l', $monday));
    $b = array('daynum'=>date('w', $monday,'','','en'));
    $allDates[] = array_merge($a,$b); 
    if($tuesday > $aYearLater)
        break 1;
    $a = array('date'=>date('Y-m-d l', $tuesday));
    $b = array('daynum'=>date('w', $tuesday,'','','en'));
    $allDates[] = array_merge($a,$b); 
    if($wednesday > $aYearLater)
        break 1;
    $a = array('date'=>date('Y-m-d l', $wednesday));
    $b = array('daynum'=>date('w', $wednesday,'','','en'));
    $allDates[] = array_merge($a,$b); 
    if($thursday > $aYearLater)
        break 1;
    $a = array('date'=>date('Y-m-d l', $thursday));
    $b = array('daynum'=>date('w', $thursday,'','','en'));
    $allDates[] = array_merge($a,$b); 
    if($friday > $aYearLater)
        break 1;
    $a = array('date'=>date('Y-m-d l', $friday));
    $b = array('daynum'=>date('w', $friday,'','','en'));
    $allDates[] = array_merge($a,$b); 
    $friday = strtotime('+1 Week', $friday);
    $saturday = strtotime('+1 Week', $saturday);
    $sunday = strtotime('+1 Week', $sunday);
    $monday = strtotime('+1 Week', $monday);
    $tuesday = strtotime('+1 Week', $tuesday);
    $wednesday = strtotime('+1 Week', $wednesday);
    $thursday = strtotime('+1 Week', $thursday);
}

foreach ($allDates as $k=>$v){
    echo $allDates[$k]['date'].'</br>'.$allDates[$k]['daynum'].'</br>';
}

how i grouping this dates weekly?
I dont want use DateTime in PHP.
thanks.
I searched stackoverflow but couldn't find an answer

Well, to start, you have an issue with all of your date calls, because I'm getting the warning date() expects at most 2 arguments, 5 given. I don't know why you're passing in empty strings and a language. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Why would you not want to use DateTime? It would be the easiest and the most sensible thing to use.

See: How to create an HTML table.

@aynber that because I use JDF library for jalali calendar which uses a function called jdate. By default, the output of this function is in persian language and it is not possible to perform calculations on it. so set language 'en'.

@Dharman because DateTime for Gregorian calendar.

JDF library: https://github.com/SCR-IR/Jalali-Date-for-All-Programming-Languages/tree/main/PHP

I still don't understand why DateTime cannot be used. If you can use date() then you can use DateTime too.

This is how I would do it:
<?php

// Set the start and end dates for the year
$year = date('Y');
$startDate = new DateTime("$year-01-01");
$endDate = new DateTime("$year-12-31");

// Create an interval of one day
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');

// Create a period from start to end date
$period = new DatePeriod($startDate, $interval, $endDate->add($interval));

// Initialize an array to hold weeks
$weeks = [];

// Loop through each date in the period
foreach ($period as $date) {
    $weekNumber = $date->format('W'); // Get the week number
    $dayOfWeek = $date->format('N'); // Get the day of the week (1 = Monday, 7 = Sunday)
    $weeks[$weekNumber][$dayOfWeek] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}

// Display the dates in an HTML table
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th><th>Saturday</th><th>Sunday</th></tr>';

foreach ($weeks as $week) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($day = 1; $day <= 7; $day++) {
        echo '<td>' . ($week[$day] ?? '') . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
?>

Snippet: https://onlinephp.io/c/5a2b8
I don't know why you don't want to use DateTime().
Anyway, this is a no-datetime-version of the code:
<?php

// Set the start and end dates for the year
$year = date('Y');
$startDate = strtotime("$year-01-01");
$endDate = strtotime("$year-12-31");

// Initialize an array to hold weeks
$weeks = [];

// Loop through each day in the year
for ($currentDate = $startDate; $currentDate <= $endDate; $currentDate += 86400) { // 86400 seconds in a day
    $weekNumber = date('W', $currentDate); // Get the week number
    $dayOfWeek = date('N', $currentDate); // Get the day of the week (1 = Monday, 7 = Sunday)
    $weeks[$weekNumber][$dayOfWeek] = date('Y-m-d', $currentDate);
}

// Display the dates in an HTML table
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th><th>Saturday</th><th>Sunday</th></tr>';

foreach ($weeks as $week) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($day = 1; $day <= 7; $day++) {
        echo '<td>' . ($week[$day] ?? '') . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
?>

Snippet: https://onlinephp.io/c/82a4f

You can simplify the code just by advancing $now by a single day. You can get the week number with date('W'), but know that if you want the week to start on Sunday, you have to do a bit of manipulation. Here's some code that will advance each day, and separate the days into weeks:
$now = mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2024);
$aYearLater = $now + 31536000;
$allDates = Array();

while($now <= $aYearLater) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d l', $now); // Formatted date
    $daynum = date('w', $now); // Day number
    $weekNum = $daynum == 0 ?  date('o-W', strtotime("+1 day",$now)) : date('o-W', $now); // If the day number is 0, then advance it by a day to move Sunday into the "next" weeknum
    $allDates[$weekNum][] = ['date' => $date, 'daynum' => $daynum];
    $now = strtotime('+1 day', $now);
}

foreach ($allDates as $week=>$days){ // Key is the Year-Weeknum, Days is the subarray
    foreach ($days as $k =>$v ) { // Go through each child day
        echo $v['date'].'</br>'.$v['daynum'].'</br>';
    }
}

Your array will look like
[
    "2024-01" => [
      0 => [
        "date" => "2024-01-01 Monday",
        "daynum" => "1",
      ],
      1 => [
        "date" => "2024-01-02 Tuesday",
        "daynum" => "2",
      ],
      2 => [
        "date" => "2024-01-03 Wednesday",
        "daynum" => "3",
      ],
      3 => [
        "date" => "2024-01-04 Thursday",
        "daynum" => "4",
      ],
      4 => [
        "date" => "2024-01-05 Friday",
        "daynum" => "5",
      ],
      5 => [
        "date" => "2024-01-06 Saturday",
        "daynum" => "6",
      ],
    ],
    "2024-02" => [
      0 => [
        "date" => "2024-01-07 Sunday",
        "daynum" => "0",
      ],
      1 => [
        "date" => "2024-01-08 Monday",
        "daynum" => "1",
      ],
....
    ]
]

